# Spring integration what if server close connection, how handle it and open while receiving arbitrary events

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I am using base code of dynamic tcp routing and extend it with help of Gary Russell,

> Sub Flow code : In here i can receive arbitrary messages with extending TcpOutboundGateway. If message is coming with arbitrary without request from client, it handles by direct message channel of ExtendedTcpOutBoundGateway

```
private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
    String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
    Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");

    boolean hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel = message.getHeaders().containsKey("irregularMessageChannelName");

    Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
    String flowRegisterKey;

    if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
        flowRegisterKey = host + port + ".extended";
    } else {
        flowRegisterKey = host + port;
    }

    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    cf.setSoTimeout(0);
    cf.setSoKeepAlive(true);

    ByteArrayCrLfSerializer byteArrayCrLfSerializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
    byteArrayCrLfSerializer.setMaxMessageSize(1048576);

    cf.setSerializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);
    cf.setDeserializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);

    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway;
    if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
        log.info("TcpRouter # createNewSubflow extended TcpOutboundGateway will be created");
        String unsolicitedMessageChannelName = (String) message.getHeaders().get("irregularMessageChannelName");
        DirectChannel directChannel = getBeanFactory().getBean(unsolicitedMessageChannelName, DirectChannel.class);
        tcpOutboundGateway = new ExtendedTcpOutboundGateway(directChannel);
    } else {
        log.info("TcpRouter # createNewSubflow extended TcpOutboundGateway will be created");
        tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    }

    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(cf);

    tcpOutboundGateway.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(new Advice[]{tcpRetryAdvice()}));

    IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(tcpOutboundGateway);

    IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
        this.flowContext.registration(flow)
            .addBean(cf)
            .id(flowRegisterKey + ".flow")
            .register();

    MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();

    this.subFlows.put(flowRegisterKey, inputChannel);
    return inputChannel;
}
```

> In here, i can handle retry advice to setup connection again.

```
@Bean
public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice tcpRetryAdvice() {
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);

    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(100);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(1000);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    RequestHandlerRetryAdvice tcpRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    tcpRetryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

    // This allows fail-controlling
    tcpRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(failMessageChannel()));

    return tcpRetryAdvice;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel failMessageChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "failMessageChannel")
public void messageAggregation(String in) {
    log.error("TcpRouter # connection retry failed with message : " + in);
}
```

but now i need to handle another scenario;

What if during receiving arbitrary messages from server connection closed ? Somehow connection can be closed from server side, I need to handle connection closed event and setup connection again to continue receiving arbitrary events.

How should i catch that event with spring integration and re-establish connection again ?

> EDIT 1

I googled some same questions and found that EventListener from this link [EventListener topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207274/spring-integration-tcp-ip-close-connection-problem) but in that link as i understood there is only one connection so in my case i am client side and using dynamic tcp routing this is why i need to implement logic to handle different connections.

> EDIT 2

Here is determine target channel

```
@Override
protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
    MessageChannel channel;
    boolean hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel = message.getHeaders().containsKey("irregularMessageChannelName");
    if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
        channel = this.subFlows.get(message.getHeaders().get("host", String.class) + message.getHeaders().get("port") + ".extended");
    } else {
        channel = this.subFlows.get(message.getHeaders().get("host", String.class) + message.getHeaders().get("port"));
    }

    if (channel == null) {
        channel = createNewSubflow(message);
    }
    return Collections.singletonList(channel);
}
```

Here is ToTCP interface

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp.input")
public interface ToTCP {
    byte[] send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port, @Header("irregularMessageChannelName") String channelName);

byte[] send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.addBean(cf)`

If you use `.addBean("someBeanName", cf)` you can check the `TcpConnectionClosedEvent`'s `connectionFactoryName` (which will be the id you gave the cf in `addBean()`).

You can then route a new message to the flow that has that factory to re-establish the connection.

Comment: Let me try and provide my feedback, Thank you

Comment: One more question Gary, ı am using here [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/dynamictcp/DynamicTcpClientApplication.java) from github. As i understood when i catch connection closed event, i need to send message again then connection will be established, am i right ?

Comment: If yes then should i autowire ToTcp in TcpRouter class or should i inject it in constructor of TcpRouter  ? 

Because if i inject in constructor then also i need to change it in  `  @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow toTcp() {
        return f -> f.route(new TcpRouter());
    } `. 

so i am a bit confused about routing a new message...

Comment: You must already have logic that sends a message to the router with appropriate headers; otherwise you would never have established a question in the first place. Simply send an appropriate message to the router with headers set up so it will be routed to the flow where the connection just closed.

Comment: Ok thank you, i think i did some arrangement in my flow and it seems working now. In case some additional recommendation, i will open another ticket. Thanks for your support

Comment: Hi Again, my TcpRouter extends AbstractMessageRouter like in your example so ı noticed that there is an method called "determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message)" so when i handle connection closed i can setup message and call determineTargetChannel... also there is a handleMessageInternal method too, am i doing it correct way ? Or call directly `send`method (`byte[] send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port)`) in event listener then also i have to deal with return result. sorry but i am confused about it.

Comment: I have added EDIT in to question that shows `determineTargetChannels` and  `@Component
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp.input")` to be more clear

Comment: It's not clear what you are unsure about. Perhaps its time to open a new question?

Comment: Ok then i will open another question. Thank you

Comment: here is more detailed question [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038187/spring-integration-handle-connection-close-event-with-event-listener-and-re-esta)