# Spring integration Handle Connection Close event with Event Listener and Re establish it while using Dynamic TCP Routing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I am using spring integration to create flow for request / response architecture and also receiving arbitrary data from server. Until this stage, i checked examples from spring-integration github and advices from @Gary Russell and @Artem Bilan.

Here is my gateway interface

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "toTcp.input")
public interface ToTCP {
    byte[] send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port, @Header("irregularMessageChannelName") String channelName);
    byte[] send(String data, @Header("host") String host, @Header("port") int port);
}
```

Here is my my TcpClientConfig

```
@Component
public class TcpClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow toTcp() {
        return f -> f.route(new TcpRouter());
    }
}
```

Here is my TcpRouter That Extends AbstractMessageRouter

```
public class TcpRouter extends AbstractMessageRouter {


    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpRouter.class);

    private final static int MAX_CACHED = 100; // When this is exceeded, we remove the LRU.

    private HashMap<String, Message<?>> connectionRegistery = new HashMap<>();

    private final LinkedHashMap<String, MessageChannel> subFlows =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, MessageChannel>(MAX_CACHED, .75f, true) {

            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, MessageChannel> eldest) {
                if (size() > MAX_CACHED) {
                    removeSubFlow(eldest);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        };

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @Override
    protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
        MessageChannel channel;
        boolean hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel = message.getHeaders().containsKey("irregularMessageChannelName");
        if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
            channel = this.subFlows.get(message.getHeaders().get("host", String.class) + message.getHeaders().get("port") + ".extended");
        } else {
            channel = this.subFlows.get(message.getHeaders().get("host", String.class) + message.getHeaders().get("port"));
        }

        if (channel == null) {
            channel = createNewSubflow(message);
        }
        return Collections.singletonList(channel);
    }


    private MessageChannel createNewSubflow(Message<?> message) {
        String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
        Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");

        boolean hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel = message.getHeaders().containsKey("irregularMessageChannelName");

        Assert.state(host != null && port != null, "host and/or port header missing");
        String flowRegisterKey;

        if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
            flowRegisterKey = host + port + ".extended";
        } else {
            flowRegisterKey = host + port;
        }

        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        cf.setSoTimeout(0);
        cf.setSoKeepAlive(true);

        ByteArrayCrLfSerializer byteArrayCrLfSerializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
        byteArrayCrLfSerializer.setMaxMessageSize(1048576);

        cf.setSerializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);
        cf.setDeserializer(byteArrayCrLfSerializer);

        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway;
        if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
            log.info("TcpRouter # createNewSubflow extended TcpOutboundGateway will be created");
            String irregularMessageChannelName = (String) message.getHeaders().get("irregularMessageChannelName");
            DirectChannel directChannel = getBeanFactory().getBean(irregularMessageChannelName, DirectChannel.class);
            tcpOutboundGateway = new ExtendedTcpOutboundGateway(directChannel);
        } else {
            log.info("TcpRouter # createNewSubflow extended TcpOutboundGateway will be created");
            tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        }

        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(cf);

        tcpOutboundGateway.setAdviceChain(Arrays.asList(new Advice[]{tcpRetryAdvice()}));

        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(tcpOutboundGateway);

        IntegrationFlowContext.IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
            this.flowContext.registration(flow)
                //.addBean(cf)
                .addBean("client_connection_" + flowRegisterKey, cf)
                .id(flowRegisterKey + ".flow")
                .register();

        MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();

        this.subFlows.put(flowRegisterKey, inputChannel);
        this.connectionRegistery.put("client_connection_" + flowRegisterKey, message);

        return inputChannel;
    }

    private void removeSubFlow(Map.Entry<String, MessageChannel> eldest) {
        String hostPort = eldest.getKey();
        this.flowContext.remove(hostPort + ".flow");
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice tcpRetryAdvice() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);

        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(100);
        backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(1000);
        backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);

        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice tcpRetryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        tcpRetryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);

        // This allows fail-controlling
        tcpRetryAdvice.setRecoveryCallback(new ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer(failMessageChannel()));

        return tcpRetryAdvice;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel failMessageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "failMessageChannel")
    public void messageAggregation(String in) {
        log.error("TcpRouter # connection retry failed with message : " + in);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ToTCP toTCP;

    @EventListener
    public void listen(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        String connectionFactoryName = event.getConnectionFactoryName();
        boolean isConnectionRegistered = this.connectionRegistery.containsKey(connectionFactoryName);
        if (isConnectionRegistered) {
            Message<?> message = this.connectionRegistery.get(connectionFactoryName);
            String host = (String) message.getHeaders().get("host");
            Integer port = (Integer) message.getHeaders().get("port");
            boolean hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel = message.getHeaders().containsKey("irregularMessageChannelName");
            if (hasThisConnectionIrregularChannel) {
                log.info("TcpRouter # listen # registered tcp connection with arbitrary message channel closed for host {} and port {}, it will open again !!", host, port);
                String unsolicitedMessageChannelName = (String) message.getHeaders().get("irregularMessageChannelName");
                toTCP.send(message.getPayload().toString(), host, port, unsolicitedMessageChannelName);
            } else {
                log.info("TcpRouter # listen # registered tcp connection closed for host {} and port {}, it will open again !!", host, port);
                toTCP.send(message.getPayload().toString(), host, port);
                            }
        } else {
            log.info("TcpRouter # listen # unregistered tcp connection closed, no action required.");
        }
    }
}
```

In case of any connection close event, I can handle it with event listener. In event listener i can understand from `connectionFactoryName` that was registered in `addBean("client_connection_" + flowRegisterKey, cf)`. Here is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003282/spring-integration-what-if-server-close-connection-how-handle-it-and-open-while) for that part

After handle which connection is closed, i should open it again to continue to receive **arbitrary data** OR make ready connection between TCP server to send any request... But i am not sure the way that i re establish connection with sending data.

Should i use

```
@Autowired
private ToTCP toTCP;
```

in TcpRouter class to send message again

OR

Should i send message directly to

```
@Override
protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message)
```

Method. I am confused about their working behaviour... Can you give me the correct idea that helps me to use more convenient way for EventListener to reestablish connection ?

Comment: Isn't sending the reconnection request just like the initial time you called it? Why are you discarding the reply when you detect the close? How does the server know this is a reconnect Vs. an initial connect?

Comment: Actually you are right, reconnection request is same with initial time i called it.  I do not want to discard but i do not know how to use it in EventListener. Server does not recognise whether it is reconnect or initial connect. According to my case they are all same. Server is straight forward, it receives new connection request and goes on. Should i use  determineTargetChannels in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually you are right, reconnection request is same with initial time i called it.

> Should i use determineTargetChannels in that case ?

No; do exactly the same in the event listener as whatever calls `ToTCP` in the first place (send a new request and handle the reply).

Comment: As you told me, i added retry advice some time ago. Retry advice try to establish by itsef automatically... am i right ? So should i still keep send message in EventListener ? On th other hand, i think that  being able to receive arbitrary message i should still re-establish connection in event listener because if i did not establish connection again, server can not send me those messages. What do you think about my concerns ?

Comment: They are for two different use cases. The retry advice is for the case where the attempt to send a request for a reply reply fails and we try again. The event listener is for when the server closes the connection and you want to re-open it. Most likely, the retry advice is no longer needed but it will still help for when there is some network problem and the connection fails.